# Disabling auto adjusment to image in CSS when zooming in/out

Tags: html, css, image

```html
<div class="footer">
  <img class="fisk" src="fisk1.jpg" alt="fisk">
</div>
```

I have a img inside a div and i want this image to keep the same size when zooming in and out, but i can't get this to work. I feel like i have tried everything and it feels like this is not possible?

I get the text to stay the same size but not the image.

Comment: How do you make the text stay the same size? Also, are you sure you want to do this? The whole point of zooming is to make things bigger...

Comment: When you say zooming, what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the solution, it seems to stay the same even during resize!

***Note: tested in my local html file, while zooming in/out!***

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <img class="fisk" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="fisk" width="100%">
</div>
```

Comment: It still scales/adjusts when ctrl+/ctrl-

Comment: @Filip I tried what you told with my local html file! the image always stays the same size!

Comment: @Filip Did this answer help you? still facing the same issue?